# ipad iphone repositioning uinavigation bar, moving it down to have a logo

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationbar

Does anyone know if the uinvagitionbar of a uinavigationcontroller can be moved down? I'd like to move it around 200 pixels down to have a logo on top. From my research, I understand that the navigationbar should not be subclassed and there are only two properties that should be changed, it's color and it's visibility. So is this impossible?

I tried moving it's frame, but to no avail.

I've seen other apps do it, but I'm thinking it might be a toolbar? Can the toolbar be repositioned?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the size of the frame of the navigations controller's view.

```
CGRect frame = navigationController.view.frame;
frame.size.height -= 200.0f;
frame.origin.y += 200.0f;
navigationController.view.frame = frame;
```

You can then add whatever view you'd like to the view or window that contains the navigationController's view.

There a few tricky things to consider if you plan on doing this by presenting a modal view controller, however.

Comment: So it worked, but everytime the screen rotates it realigns back on top. Do I have to go to every view controller and change the didrotate method, or is there a simpler way to keep it fixed there? Thanks.

Comment: Does it have anything to do with the autoresizingmasks and autoresizesubview properties? I'm fiddling around with them but nothing is happening.

Comment: Are you displaying this navigation controller from your app delegate? Modally?

Comment: Yeah I allocate and display it in the app delegate, but not modally.

UINavigationController* navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
[self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];

Sorry, I don't know how to do the code quotes.

Comment: I think a solution would be to subclass uiviewcontroller for all of my viewcontrolers, and then have the four frames for the four orientations. Then, I will adjust the frame in the viewcontroller subclass's init, and didrotate? Is there a method to find the current orientation?

Comment: You should be able to set the frame size with a line of code just below the alloc/init and then addSubview.

Comment: Right, that works. But whenever I rotate the device the frame resizes back to the top. Any suggestions?

Comment: I even tried "navigationController.view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;" but that doesn't work either. Really stomped on this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the self.navigationController and put another navigation bar in the code which will move according to your frame set.

Yes the tool bar can be repositioned. Just take a control in your code and set its frame as per your requirement.

Happy Coding...